# python how to do 2 conditions in a for loop? (for comparing a list)

Tags: python

I have a list of keywords:

```
keywords = ["dog", "cat", "bird", "pig"]
```

and a parsed string:

```
title = title.split() 
content = content.split()
```

I want to have a for loop and print "yes" if either title or content contains any of the keywords.

How can I have 2 conditions in 1 for loop?

Comment: Quite literally make 2 conditions inside a for loop... With what exactly are you struggling? Did you try that and got an error?

Comment: Did you find the answers helpful? Please upvote + accept if you do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```py
keywords = ["dog","cat","bird","pig"]
for word in keywords:
    if word in title or word in content:
        print("yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I think the answer you are looking for looks something like this:

```
for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in title or keyword in content:
       print("yes")
```